# Is it possible to auto populate one field from different table in ServiceNow?

Tags: servicenow

Is this possible to connect two field in different table  ?

Explanation :-  In a custom application there is two modules , In first table there is one field called "Application ID" and in 2nd table also there is same field called "Application ID" .

Requirement is : we need to fill the first table first and when we move to 2nd table the "Application ID" should be auto populate from first table which is filled before . In this case what condition or what rule we need to put or we need to write some script ? can any one help me on this ???

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is you need to write after business rule to run on update.

The business rule must be created for first table

The sample script is below

```
 (function executeRule(current, previous /*null when async*/) { 
        
  var gr = new GlideRecord('the_name_of_the_second_table');
        
        
   current.application_id = gr.application_id;
        
   gr.update();
        
            
  }(current, previous);
```